# Angular 4/Java Text File Encoding

Tags: java, angular, file

I have a problem with text file encoding. Here's the thing : I generate some text and I need to save it into file, and that goes well. I save this file (only to check out it's encoding). File saved on backend is encoded using CP1250 (as I wanted).

Then I send it to front-end using ResponseEntity object.

```
public ResponseEntity testFile(byte[] textToFile, String filename, String fileExtension) {

    String txt = new String(textToFile, Charset.forName("Cp1250"));

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccessControlExposeHeaders(Collections.singletonList("Content-Disposition"));
    headers.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
    headers.set("Content-Type","text/plain");

//Saving file on drive (test purposes)
    try {
        writeToFileLocal(txt, filename); //and there I get a file I need, encoded with widnows-1250
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return  new ResponseEntity<>(txt, headers, HttpStatus.OK); //but after recieving this on front-end I get file encoded with UTF-8, but I need windows-1250
}
```

But when I recieve this file on front-end, the file is encoded in UTF-8. Somewhere there it's converted and I don't have an idea how to fix that.

Here's my front-end piece :

```
this.http.post('/api/getFile',params, { headers: headers })
        .toPromise().then(response => this.saveToFileSystem(response),
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            if (err.error instanceof Error){
                this.pushMSG('ERROR: ' + err.error.message, 'error');
            }else {
                this.pushMSG('Server error, val: ' + err.status + ' , body: ' + err.error,"error");
            }
        }
    );

private saveToFileSystem(response: any) {
    const contentDispositionHeader: string = response.headers.get('Content-Disposition');
    const parts: string[] = contentDispositionHeader.split(';');
    const filename = parts[1].split('=')[1];
    const blob = new Blob([response._body], { type: 'text/plain;'});
    saveAs(blob, filename, true);
}
```

And there I get that UTF-8 file. How can I get this encoded with windows-1250?

Comment: What's the point in transforming the byte array to a String? Just send the byte array directly. And specify the charset in the response headers: "text/plain; charset=Cp1250".

Comment: @JBNizet Okay, I send byte array and specyfied in header charset as you wrote. But I still have a file in UTF-8. I get response headers :
`Access-Control-Expose-Headers:Content-Disposition
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=filename.txt
Content-Length:615
Content-Type:text/plain;charset=Cp1250`

Comment: What happens when you don't use the JS code to load the file, but simply use the browser or a rest client? What happens when you specify the right charset when constructing the Blob?

Comment: @JBNizet Tried specyfy charest in Blob, but nothing changed. See how I wrote this : `const blob = new Blob([response._body], { type: 'text/plain; charset=Cp1250'});`
You wrote what happens when I don't use the JS code but brower or rest, but I don't really know what you mean and how to do that.

Comment: Indeed, I asked that. So, what's the answer?

Comment: @JBNizet just updated the comment. I don't know how you mean and how to do that.

Comment: You take the URL of the resource (`http://localhost:8080/api/getFile`, probably), and you use a rest client (like postman) to send a POST request with the neccessary headers to that URL. Note, BTW, that a resource allowing to download a file should use GET, not POST.

Comment: Okay. I managed to change it a little bit. Now it works like you wrote. I use `window.location.href = localhost:8080/api/getFile` and it opens that file in browser window. When I click right mouse button -> save as -> text file it's saved with Cp1250 encoding (hurray!). But now, is there a possibility to make this file downloaded automatically by browser with that encoding?